# recursive setTimeout() causes low cpu usage

Tags: javascript, timeout, progress

I am executing a long calculation in JS. During the calculation I want to show a progress bar which gets updated after each step. Due to properly trigger the DOM refresh I use setTimeout to enqueue the steps. I built myself a function like this:

```
var sequence = function (ar, callback, finalCallback) {
    if (ar && ar.length) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            callback && callback(ar.shift());
            sequence(ar, callback, finalCallback);
        }, 0);
    } else {
        finalCallback && finalCallback();
    }
};
```

This works nearly as expected. The calcultion gets properly executed as well as the DOM manipulation I do within the callback. The only problem is, that all the stuff is significally slow. The CPU usage during the calculation is only at 20%.

Is there anything wrong with my code? I thought, all the single steps are just enqueued and due to the timeout of 0 get executed without a 'real' pause but when the browser has nothing to do anymore.

Edit: I tried to execute that in Chrome and Firefox and both behave the same way.
Also I tried to move the actual callback invocation outside the setTimeout. It makes no difference.

According to the advice I tried setInterval instead of setTimout like so:

```
var sequence = function (ar, callback, finalCallback) {
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (ar && ar.length) {
            callback && callback(ar.shift());
        } else {
            finalCallback && finalCallback();
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 0);
};
```

It behaves exactly like the setTimeout version.

And here is a fiddle, that shows the stuff:

https://jsfiddle.net/by6oovhz/8/

If you remove the setTimout you'll see how fast it should actually be (but then the DOM doesn't get updated anymore).

Comment: what happens when you set this setTimeout to something else then 0,, can you try with number 5 (mil secs) for ex.. JS is single threaded so I thought maybe this 0 has some throttle

Comment: it makes no difference whether I use 0 or 5. Just tried it.

Comment: 5 milliseconds is much faster than the human eye can detect. 500 seems a more reasonable interval.

Comment: would it be possible to build jsfiddle somehow.. think that we could help you better that way..

Comment: I just added a fiddle which shows the effect.

Answer (score 2):

I just found the problem. The reason for that setTimeout behaviour is, that this method has always a small timeout, even if you pass 0 as parameter. Here you can read more about it and find the link to a workarond. It uses window.postMessage to create a function, that really has a timeout of zero.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting

Comment: great find @mightyplow that 4milsecs just added up :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your func has fired whole bunch of timeout obj to the window..
You can try to alter your function to something like this,, to create TO and then to remove it..

```
myVar = setTimeout(function(){ mycallback }, 0); // id of timeout
```

and latter in the code remove it

```
clearTimeout(myVar);
```

or you can try to change your logic to use setInterval maybe?

hth, k

Comment: I update my post. Sounded promising but didn't help. Also when I try to clear the timeout after every step doesn't help. Maybe the garbage collection comes into play and slows down the function?

Comment: I would not suggest interval in that way, thats worse then timeout before :)

Comment: But why? It's not recursive anymore and so gets only created once.

Comment: ohh, right, didn't saw you removed recursion.. sorry

Comment: np. I'm glad for every advice =)